# Running AJAX query to refresh div with php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on a multi-step query form which can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/47/.

I'm trying to submit the variables via jQuery AJAX (process.php will handle the processing) and refresh the div **last-step** with the div in the process.php called **result**. How can I achieve this?

I've so far managed to accomplish this using the jQuery form plugin by malsup (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and now need to using the jQuery AJAX method to accomplish it as part of a strict specification.

This is the code I had been using (with the jQuery form plugin):

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 

$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#result',  
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  
    success:       showResponse   
}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 

$('#task5_booking').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
    }); 
});  

// pre-submit callback 

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData); 
    // alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
}

// post-submit callback 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.ajax` to handle the last step:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
   else if (whichStep == 'last-step') {
        $.ajax( {
            url:'urltophp.php',
            data: {}, // your data
            dataType: 'json', //your datatype
            type: 'POST',   //or GET
            success: function(r) {
                //your callback here...
            }
        });
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
$('#task5_booking').submit(function(e) { 
    $(e).preventDefault();  //prevent the default form submit()

    var formData = $(this).serialize(); //serialize the form fields data...


    $.ajax( {
        url:'urltophp.php',
        data: formData, // your data
        dataType: 'json', //your datatype
        type: 'POST',   //or GET
        success: showResponse
    });

    //$(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    //return false; 
    //}); 
});
```

**Change this:**

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

**To this:**

```
function showResponse(responseText)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to show the method I am currently using. How can I implement that into the code you've presented?

Comment: Thanks brother so I'm guessing that I replace your code with mine? Will test as soon as I get home and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @CJS: Look carefully what happens in code, that will help you ;)

Comment: I'm very confused about the placement of the code - where am I meant to put everything?

Answer (score 1):

use http://api.jquery.com/load/ .
it's like using .ajax, only easier and fits your requirements.

`$('#last-step').load(url, data, function(){})` sends a post request, and fills the html content of 'last-step' with whatever the url printed out into the response html.